# How to determine existing a RSU at a junction?

Tags: omnet++, veins

i want to determine Is there a RSU at a junction? Is a method or a way to achieve my goal?
Can any one please helpe me.

Answer (score 2):

Veins 4.4 offers [a function to get a list of all junctions](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L171) and, for each of those, [a function to get a junction's position](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L178). This should allow for a good approximation of whether an RSU can serve a junction.

If you want to be more precise, you would need to know the junction's exact geometry. It is known to SUMO (though not yet exposed via the TraCI API), but you can easily extend the API by a function to do this yourself.

Comment: Maybe, you want to accept this answer as the solution to mark your question as answered. Therefore, this post can be more effective for helping people with a similar problem.